# Eclipse SWT plugin validation error (Luna) despite everything matching

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I recently moved my workspace from Juno to Luna, and now get plugin validation errors constantly.  Funny thing is that everything should be just fine.

Configuration:

> *** Date: Monday, August 1, 2016 at 8:38:51 PM Central Daylight Time
>
> *** Platform Details:
>
> *** System properties: applicationXMI=org.eclipse.ui.workbench/LegacyIDE.e4xmi
>   awt.toolkit=sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit
>   eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
>   eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700 eclipse.commands=-os macosx
>   -ws cocoa
>   -arch x86_64
>   -showsplash
>   -launcher
>   ...

The target platform is set to be the running platform.
[image: target platform dialog]

The arguments used in the Run Configuration just use target, as in

> -os ${target.os} -ws ${target.ws} -arch ${target.arch} -nl ${target.nl} -consoleLog

But I still get a plugin validation error.
[image]
What's going on?
(I even get this error with a test plugin I wrote long ago using the plugin Wizard.)
My MANIFEST.MF doesn't have any tricky system dependent stuff in it.
And neither does the plugin; it's vanilla Java 6 code.

Comment: In the Target Platform preferences select 'Running Platform' and click Edit. Check what the 'Environment' page of the Edit Target Definition says.

Comment: Yes @greg449 that was it.  Thanks. The Environment said it was x86.  Deleting that (leaving it blank) solved the problem with validation *and* got rid of all the compile errors in the plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the target platform is for the correct environment.

Open the 'Preferences' and go to 'Plug-in Development > Target Platform'. Edit your active target platform and look at the 'Environment' tab to check that the environment settings are correct.